# 自作vagrantボックスで初回起動時のみパスワードを聞かれてしまう

Tags: vagrant

vagrant用にCentOS6.6のボックスを自作したところ、初回のvagrant up で必ずパスワードを聞かれてしまいます。

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'ns' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> ns: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> ns: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> ns: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    ns: Adapter 1: nat
    ns: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> ns: Forwarding ports...
    ns: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> ns: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> ns: Booting VM...
==> ns: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    ns: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    ns: SSH username: vagrant
    ns: SSH auth method: private key
    ns: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    ns: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    ns: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:
```

一応参考書(実践vagrant)を元につくったつもりですが、このようにパスワードを聞かれてしまいます。ここでパスワードを入れると通常通り処理が進み、これ以後何回vagrant upを実行しても、パスワードを聞かれることはありません。

SSH周りであろうとは推測できるのですが、見逃している箇所が分かりません。思い当たるであろうポイントを教えていただけると嬉しいです。よろしくお願いします。

vagrant 1.7.2
ホストOS: ubuntu 15.04
ゲストOS: CentOS 6.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

自己解決しました。やはりsshの鍵設定を誤っていました。
解決方法はいたって簡単で、自作box側のvagrantユーザー操作により

```
cd ~/.ssh
curl -O https://raw.github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant
curl -O https://raw.github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub
mv vagrant.pub authorized_keys
chmod 600
```

とするだけでした。
これらのファイルはvagrantの作者が公開している、vagrantボックスを自作するのに使える共通の公開鍵情報です。
秘密鍵に対応する vagrant という名前のファイルは対応するクライアントに配布するものなのでダウンロード必須ではありませんが、なんとなく念のためダウンロードしました。

私の場合、この秘密鍵の方を誤って公開鍵として authorized_key としていることが問題で、終わってみれば全く初歩的なミスだったという次第です。

後進の人が自分でカスタマイズドボックスを作るときの参考になればと思い、自己解答としてここに挙げておきます。